# Related questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Surely has an answer already (at least on another SE).

Asking more than one question in one post endangers you to "Maybe I could have been more focused" (Lloyd Cole) - but what if those two questions are closely related and it thus seems silly to open two questions, especially if the needed amount of background set-up is high?

Answer (score -2):

In no scenario is it correct to post more than one question; the publications should concentrate on a single objective if there is a higher objective and 2 previous questions are required to reach that objective then it really requires 3 questions even...

for example I had an idea; Since I'm new, I wanted to learn how an experienced player analyzes the game and how he makes decisions; therefore prepare a series of approximately 5 questions, since the game is complex and extensive; In the end, the recommendation was to divide this into separate publications, one for each question; in the end I personally got my top goal. but the community has 5 posts with 5 independent questions that can be better received and objective.

knowing how SE works this promotes the quality of the questions and answers; content that is worth writing and reading and maybe not reading something that does not interest me...

On other sites there are reports of closing questions because the question is very broad and should focus on a single problem.

Even what is acceptable is to create new questions with new doubts making references to previous questions and some research done.